# Where to store dictionary key for Keychain (Locksmith)

Tags: swift, keychain

I'm exploring the Locksmith API (https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) for storing data in keychain. I need to store a JSON Web Token within keychain.

I save the token as follows:

```
try Locksmith.saveData(["someAccountId": "someTokenValue"], forUserAccount: "userEmail")
```

I'm wondering where I could store the `forUserAccount` parameter, so the next time the user opens the app I can access the token.

Would it be safe to store this within `NSUserDefaults` or would this be bad practice?

Comment: were you able to save the dictionary into keychain? I want todo the same exact thing